# Where should I ask why it is difficult to kill a fly with bare hands?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

There are a lot of flies in our house this summer. It is rather difficult to kill them by hand. Yet I don't want to use other tactics. Normally I don't kill a fly but the circumstances made me one. I want to know why it is so hard to kill them. So I can improve my tactics using my bare hands only. But where must I ask? On the biology site maybe?

Comment: You want to know "why" or you want to know how to improve your fly killing?

Comment: @VLAZ want to know why and on basis of that knowledge improve the killing.

Comment: Check lifehacks.se

Comment: I'm not sure there is an applicable stack exchange site for that. Lifehacks can suggest ways to eliminate and drive away flies but I'm not sure "why is fly killing hard" is quite on topic anywhere. The biggest problem is that we have no idea what and how you're trying.

Comment: @rene You were right! The question is already there! Thanks. Now I can proceed better I hope. And without remorse...

Answer (score 6):

As you discovered, the question was already asked on [Lifehacks Stack Exchange](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/): [Is there any way to kill a fly without a flyswatter?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1798/5345). I guess it falls under

> - looking for simple and practical tips to life's everyday problems that may not have an *obvious* solution

as mentioned in their [Help Center](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The question was also asked here (a duplicaat of the one you linked though): https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/13656/killing-flies-with-your-bare-hands